# Writing git commit messages

Tags: git

When writing a commit message, what is the difference between `git -m "message"` and `git commit -am "message"`

Have been listening to a tutorial and the guy did not clearly explain the difference between the two

Answer (score 1):

The `-a` flag adds to the commit all currently tracked files with changes. It will not add new files. It is unrelated to the message.

From the [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html):

```
-a
--all
Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and 
deleted, but new files you have not told git about are not affected.
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you will do

```
//tell git to stage all the files
git add . 

//now commit all the staged files with this message
git commit -m "message"


//Assuming you have just modified existing files in git repo.. you could use this as a shortcut
git commit -am "message"

//meaning, stage all the modified files and commit with this message.
```

Answer (score 1):

`git -m message` adds a commit with the current added files and the given message, while `git -am message` adds all the tracked files then commits with the current message.

you can read more about [adding files to your repository here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Committing-Your-Changes)